# What is the magnitude of the tangential, normal and total accelerations here

Tags: kinematics, vectors

The question is as follow:

> A particle moves in the xy plane with velocity $\vec{v}=a\hat{i}+(bt)\hat{j}$ at time $t=\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{b}$ , find the magnitude of the tangential, normal and total acceleration.

If I differentiate it I get $a = b\hat{j}$ (i.e. $|\vec{a}| = b$). But if I write $|\vec v|= \sqrt{a^2+b^2t^2}$ and then solve for acceleration ,I get $|\vec a| = {(b^2t)\over\sqrt{a^2+t^2b^2}}$. I can't match this result with the previous one. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivative is wrong. If you take the time derivative of $\vec{v}$, you should get $\vec{a}=\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=b\hat{j}$.

Note that in this case, it's not correct to take the time derivative of the magnitude $|\vec{v}|$. This only tells you the rate of change of speed, but this is not equal to $|\vec{a}|$.

Consider the case where a point is moving around a circle at constant speed. In this case, we have $\frac{d|\vec{v}|}{dt}=0$, since the speed is a constant. However, $a\neq 0$. This is because the direction of $\vec{v}$ is changing, and some acceleration is needed to make this change happen.

Comment: So what should we call d|v|/dt ? ,if not acceleration. Is this the total acceration?

Comment: There's not a term for it as far as I know. It's just the time derivative of speed.

Comment: What should be the answer to the question.

Comment: I cannot solve the problem explicitly for you since this looks like a homework question. But note that $\vec{a}$ is just the total acceleration. To find the tangential acceleration, you have to find the component of the acceleration *along* the direction of the velocity. Think about the angle between the acceleration and velocity vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this equation resembles the one for a projectile coming down (with +y down).  If you put the given time in the velocity equation, you get the components (and direction) for the velocity at that time. The acceleration is in the y direction, but you can get the components of the acceleration which are parallel and perpendicular to the velocity.